# <span> inside <a> link issue

Tags: css

I have a link for headline, like the following,

```
<a href="#">Cat<span class="more">See More</span></a>
```

You see I have  inside  in order to flow "See More" to the right, so I have the following css

```
.more {float:right;}
a{text-decoration:none;width:150px;display:block;}
a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}
```

I expect that when I hover over the text "Cat", the "See More" is underlined, but it does not work in IE/Firefox, it works in Chrome though.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZW9tt/1/

Anyone know why?

Comment: Floating takes the element out of the flow...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Anyone know why?

What you're seeing in IE and Firefox is actually expected behavior, described in the [CSS2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#lining-striking-props):

> Note that text decorations are not propagated to floating and absolutely positioned descendants, nor to the contents of atomic inline-level descendants such as inline blocks and inline tables.

But wait, there's more:

> Some user agents have implemented text-decoration by propagating the decoration to the descendant elements as opposed to preserving a constant thickness and line position as described above. This was arguably allowed by the looser wording in CSS2. SVG1, CSS1-only, and CSS2-only user agents may implement the older model and still claim conformance to this part of CSS 2.1. (This does not apply to UAs developed after this specification was released.)

Given that Chrome is a CSS2.1 browser, believe it or not, it's actually exhibiting a bug (which happens to have just been patched!). [Here's the bug report.](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18611)

If you need to apply the underline to the floated span, you'll need to apply it explicitly to `a:hover .more` as well:

```
a:hover, a:hover .more { text-decoration: underline; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
 a:hover, a:hover .more {text-decoration:underline;}
```

Comment: This is pretty obvious. Maybe I'm mistaken, but I think the OP wanted to know *why* this happens.

Comment: I guess I expected more from a seasoned user such as yourself. Yep, like Šime Vidas says, but that's all you can muster?

Comment: Yeah, it's that kind of morning.

Answer (score 0):

How about only targeting the span aswell?

```
.more {float:right;}
a{text-decoration:none;width:150px;display:block;}
a:hover, a:hover span {text-decoration:underline;}
```

Answer (score -1):

does this work?

```
a:hover span.more{text-decoration:underline;}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not put the class on the A link instead?

Answer (score -1):

why not use a dotted border bottom as is much more interesting.

```
.more {float:right;}
a:link {text-decoration:none;width:150px;display:block;}
a:hover, a:hover span {border-bottom:dotted 1px #000;}
```

Comment: Why is a dotted border more interesting? Note that border and text decoration are utterly different things.

Comment: I know but I found this was more interesting to put a dotted border under a link instead of underline and remove it on rollover.

Answer (score -1):

```
.more{float:right;cursor:pointer/* for ie6 */;}
a{display:block;width:150px;text-decoration:none;}
a:hover,a:hover span{text-decoration:underline;}
```

Comment: Please explain what's happening here.