# CSS: text-decoration unable to remove overline

Tags: html, css

I am trying to remove text-decoration from the first letter using the `p::first-letter` selector. But for some unknown reason i am unable to do that.

```css
p::first-line {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: overline;
}
p::first-letter {
  text-decoration: none;
  /*text-decoration-color: rgba(59, 119, 191, 0.68);*/
  display: block;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(59, 119, 191, 0.68);
  margin: 0px 2px 1px 0;
  padding: 5px 13px 5px 11px;
  color: #b1ffea;
}
```

```html
<h2>Heading <a href="#"><span class="anchor">#</span></a></h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur eaque enim eveniet facere incidunt inventore necessitatibus non quas, repellat sed ullam unde ut vitae! Asperiores ducimus laborum magnam officia repellendus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis ipsum laborum sunt voluptate voluptates voluptatum. A architecto beatae delectus eos itaque magnam nostrum perferendis, provident quis quos repellendus similique vitae!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <a href="#">some link</a> adipisicing elit. Ducimus itaque numquam voluptatem. Ad aspernatur consequuntur deserunt et expedita facilis id, iste maxime minus nisi odit quaerat quisquam quod tempora velit?
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos <a href="#">another link</a> illo iure magni odio quas, sint totam ut. Aliquam ipsa recusandae voluptatem! A consectetur deserunt eos quaerat rerum. Dolores, quod voluptatem.</p>
```

**Update:**

Okay, I got it working by Chrome by enabling "Experimental Web Platform features". For some reason prefix `-webkit-` wasn't able to trigger this behavior. Here is the working code.

```
p::first-letter{
        text-decoration: overline;
        text-decoration-color: rgba(59, 119, 191, 0.68);
        display: block;
        color: red;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: rgba(59, 119, 191, 0.68);
        margin: 0px 2px 1px 0;
        padding: 5px 13px 5px 11px;
        color: #b1ffea;
    }
```

Comment: Take off p::first-line styling it is overriding your first-charecter styling

Comment: but i want that overline in the first line except for the first character

Comment: ya im sorry i got that

Comment: You could do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/bp7t1L47/  Notice that i had to use hex for bgr color, rather than rgba, because transparency made overline visible (i see what you have tried to do, in commented line)

Comment: `text-decoration-color` is not working

Comment: While both `::first-letter` and `::first-line` *"only support a small subset of CSS properties"*, `text-decoration` is actually among both of these. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line Also, CanIUse does not report any known issues. Looks like the one found by OP is missing.

Comment: @Cody, actually, it is working, as you can see in example, but, as mentioned, usage of transparency on your background color for 'L', makes black overline from first line pseudo element visible.

Comment: Yes, It is only working in firefox not chrome. I have even tried to prefix
`-webkit-` to `text-decoration-color` property. But still not working in chrome

Comment: Down with prefixes!

Comment: What do you mean ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply add:

```
p::first-letter {
    float: left;
}
```

So it is:

```css
p::first-line {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: overline;
}
p::first-letter {
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  /*text-decoration-color: rgba(59, 119, 191, 0.68);*/
  display: block;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(59, 119, 191, 0.68);
  margin: 0px 2px 1px 0;
  padding: 5px 13px 5px 11px;
  color: #b1ffea;
}
```

```html
<h2>Heading <a href="#"><span class="anchor">#</span></a></h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur eaque enim eveniet facere incidunt inventore necessitatibus non quas, repellat sed ullam unde ut vitae! Asperiores ducimus laborum magnam officia repellendus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis ipsum laborum sunt voluptate voluptates voluptatum. A architecto beatae delectus eos itaque magnam nostrum perferendis, provident quis quos repellendus similique vitae!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <a href="#">some link</a> adipisicing elit. Ducimus itaque numquam voluptatem. Ad aspernatur consequuntur deserunt et expedita facilis id, iste maxime minus nisi odit quaerat quisquam quod tempora velit?
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos <a href="#">another link</a> illo iure magni odio quas, sint totam ut. Aliquam ipsa recusandae voluptatem! A consectetur deserunt eos quaerat rerum. Dolores, quod voluptatem.</p>
```

Comment: Why does this work?

Comment: @11684: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853100/span-inside-a-link-issue

Answer (score 2):

Not sure,if this is the right solution for it.

but yes,we can skip text-decoration using text-decoration-skip [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481318/css-text-decoration-property-cannot-be-overridden-by-child-element/4481356),[link2](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-decoration-skip/),but it did not seem to be a good fit here.

I have tried to make L and the rest of the content as separate elements and add text-decoration to it(i know its not the right),but could help you

```css
div{
  display:flex;
}
p.overline::first-line{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration:overline;
}

p:first-child::first-letter {
  text-decoration: none;
  /*text-decoration-color: rgba(59, 119, 191, 0.68);*/

  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(59, 119, 191, 0.68);
  margin: 0px 2px 1px 0;
  padding: 5px 13px 5px 11px;
  color: #b1ffea;
}
```

```html
<h2>Heading <a href="#"><span class="anchor">#</span></a></h2>
<div>
<p >L</p>

  
<p class="overline">orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur eaque enim eveniet facere incidunt inventore necessitatibus non quas, repellat sed ullam unde ut vitae! Asperiores ducimus laborum magnam officia repellendus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis ipsum laborum sunt voluptate voluptates voluptatum. A architecto beatae delectus eos itaque magnam nostrum perferendis, provident quis quos repellendus similique vitae!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <a href="#">some link</a> adipisicing elit. Ducimus itaque numquam voluptatem. Ad aspernatur consequuntur deserunt et expedita facilis id, iste maxime minus nisi odit quaerat quisquam quod tempora velit?
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos <a href="#">another link</a> illo iure magni odio quas, sint totam ut. Aliquam ipsa recusandae voluptatem! A consectetur deserunt eos quaerat rerum. Dolores, quod voluptatem.</p>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit hack-y, but you can easily get rid of the undesired overline by painting a small block of color over the top, using the `::after` pseudo-element.

```css
p::first-line {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: overline;
}

p::first-letter {
  text-decoration: none;
  /*text-decoration-color: rgba(59, 119, 191, 0.68);*/
  display: block;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(59, 119, 191, 0.68);
  margin: 0px 2px 1px 0;
  padding: 5px 13px 5px 11px;
  color: #b1ffea;
}

p {
position: relative;
}

p::after {
content: '';
display:block;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:10px;
width: 16px;
height: 8px;
background-color: rgb(122,163,212);
}
```

```html
<h2>Heading <a href="#"><span class="anchor">#</span></a></h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur eaque enim eveniet facere incidunt inventore necessitatibus non quas, repellat sed ullam unde ut vitae! Asperiores ducimus laborum magnam officia repellendus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis ipsum laborum sunt voluptate voluptates voluptatum. A architecto beatae delectus eos itaque magnam nostrum perferendis, provident quis quos repellendus similique vitae!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <a href="#">some link</a> adipisicing elit. Ducimus itaque numquam voluptatem. Ad aspernatur consequuntur deserunt et expedita facilis id, iste maxime minus nisi odit quaerat quisquam quod tempora velit?
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos <a href="#">another link</a> illo iure magni odio quas, sint totam ut. Aliquam ipsa recusandae voluptatem! A consectetur deserunt eos quaerat rerum. Dolores, quod voluptatem.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could hide that using pseudo selector as below,

```css
p::first-line{
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration:overline;
  z-index:-1;
  position:absolute;
}
p::first-letter {
  display: block;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
}
p::before{
  content:'';
  width:10px;
  height:1px;
  background:rgba(250,250,250,1);
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<h2>Heading <a href="#"><span class="anchor">#</span></a></h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur eaque enim eveniet facere incidunt inventore necessitatibus non quas, repellat sed ullam unde ut vitae! Asperiores ducimus laborum magnam officia repellendus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis ipsum laborum sunt voluptate voluptates voluptatum. A architecto beatae delectus eos itaque magnam nostrum perferendis, provident quis quos repellendus similique vitae!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <a href="#">some link</a> adipisicing elit. Ducimus itaque numquam voluptatem. Ad aspernatur consequuntur deserunt et expedita facilis id, iste maxime minus nisi odit quaerat quisquam quod tempora velit?
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos <a href="#">another link</a> illo iure magni odio quas, sint totam ut. Aliquam ipsa recusandae voluptatem! A consectetur deserunt eos quaerat rerum. Dolores, quod voluptatem.</p>
```

Here too if I change `p::before` `background:transparent;` won't work, as in background it consist of `text-decoration:overline;`. So this is how you could hide that. Just get correct `background-color` for your `pseudo ::before background-color`.

Another issue is both `::first-line` and `::first-letter` doesn't support all CSS styling properties.